# When and why use object as a class property

Tags: oop

Currently i am learning swift. I need a concept of OOP. Suppose, i have two classes

```
class Person {
    var residence: Residence?
}

class Residence {
    var numberOfRooms = 1
}
```

`Person` class use a object of `Residence` as a property. Please tell me When and why use object as a class property?

Comment: Compared to what other options? Structs? What are you going to do with these classes in future? So many questions and possible answers...

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing here is called **composition** and it's an important OOP principle. Composition is being described as a *has-a* relation - in your example a Person *has-a* residence. As to when use it, it helps if you ask yourself if there is a *has-a* relation between your objects.

Another very common example of composition would be a car class which has-a (okay has-four) wheel(s) - code is in Java:

```
class Car {
    private Wheel[] wheels;
}
```